# Replace, Filter SOAP Request using Tomcat OR Web Service Proxy

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, proxy

I have 2 servers, first server is generating a SOAP request and send it to the 2nd server "It is doing user authentication".

The first server is generating the SOAP message incorrectly and there is no way to correct it from this server.

But if i edit the received soap message from the 1st server, by deleting or replacing just 1 tag then it will work correctly.

I heard many options that can be implemented as following:

1. Using Tomcat Filter, to replace that wrong tag by whitespace or delete it from the received request.
2. Using web service proxy, so the first server will communicate with this proxy with any message and it will correct it then redirect it to the 2nd server correctly, and the soap response will back to the proxy that will send it to the first server.

So, I need any help in any of those options, Filtering using tomcat or web service proxy or any other solution.

The generated soap request from first server is the following:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <authenticateGenericChallengeCallParms xmlns="authenticationV9:wsdl">
      <authenticateGenericChallenge>
            <userId xmlns="">test</userId>
      </authenticateGenericChallenge>
    </authenticateGenericChallengeCallParms>
</Body>
```

But the correct message is like that without this tag "authenticateGenericChallenge"

```
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <authenticateGenericChallengeCallParms xmlns="authenticationV9:wsdl">
            <userId xmlns="">test</userId>
    </authenticateGenericChallengeCallParms>
</Body>
```